# using csv with python 2.7, working with DictReader

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a while now. I am trying to take a csv file, extract all rows, concantenate 2 values, take those 2 values to calculate distance from a third value separate of the csv, store the distance with the correct data from the csv, finally I need to find the shortest distance and return a dict with all the values i have not used yet.

```
    with open(filename,'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    #create a multi-dimensional dictionary with the store name as keyword
    new_dict = {}
    try:
        for row in reader:
            new_dict[row['name']] ={}
            new_dict[row['name']]['name'] = row['name']
            new_dict[row['name']]['dist'] = {}
            new_dict[row['name']]['address'] = row['address']
            new_dict[row['name']]['city'] = row['city']
            new_dict[row['name']]['state'] = row['state']
            new_dict[row['name']]['zip'] = row['zip']

            latt = str(row['latitude']) 
            longi = str(row['longitude'])
            #concantenate latt and longi for use in grate_circle distance calculation
            pharm_loc = latt + ','+ longi
            #add distance from usr_loc for each store to dict for each store
            new_dict[row['name']]['dist'] = str(calc_dist(usr_loc, store_loc))
```

I finally got this part fixed, now I need help filtering out all but the closest result for 'dist'... I cannot seem to wrap my head around this for some reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---EDIT---
updated code that is working now. this produces a multidimensional dict as follows... 
{'CONTINENTAL ': {'city': 'TOPEKA', 'dist': '50.3131329882', 'name': 'CONTINENTAL PHARMACY LLC', 'zip': '66603', 'state': 'KS', 'address': '821 SW 6TH AVE'}, 'DILLON ': {'city': 'TOPEKA', 'dist': '48.3573823197', 'name': 'DILLON PHARMACY', 'zip': '66605', 'state': 'KS', 'address': '2010 SE 29TH ST'}}

There are a lot more entries in the dict, I just need to filter down to the closest location and return only the values for that location.

Comment: In what way is it going wrong? It would also help to provide a small sample of your input data. It doesnt have to be real data, just representative of the input you are dealing with.

Comment: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 7; 2 is required

Comment: `datalist = dict(reader)` this is suspect. You shouldnt need to do this. After all the DictReader is effectively a list of dicts. So converting it to a dict doesn't make so much sense. Also `latt = datalist['Lattitude']` should this and all the other lines within this loop not be `latt = row['Lattitude']`?

Comment: i added that after reader['business_loc'] = reader[latt + ',' + longi] returned a DictReader doesn't have a __get_item__ attribute

Comment: inside the loop you should be using `row` and not `reader`. You are iterating over the dict reader and each iteration produces a dict that you are calling `row`. So e.g. `latt = row['Lattitude']`.